# No sound when iOS screen off and using Google Maps navigation?

Tags: ios, audio, google-maps, navigation

I'm using latest versions of iOS and Google Maps on an iPhone 7, and when I turn the screen off, I do not hear turn-by-turn directions when using the navigation feature of Google Maps. Yet, according to the "Battery saving tips" of the [Google Maps app documentation](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3273406?visit_id=1-636109402581671589-221536163&rd=1&co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&oco=0), I should still hear the sounds.

I verified this by turning off the screen (pushing power button) a few seconds before the next turn navigation came up. Then verified it was working by leaving the screen on for the next turn. The phone is not connected to any bluetooth devices either.

Also, the Google Maps settings all seem to indicate that sounds are all enabled properly (volume icon on map is set to "unmuted"; under navigation settings, all relevant-looking settings are enabled; etc.).

Any ideas why this would not be working for me? I've yet to try a restart of phone nor have I tried a reset of phone. (Will eventually try those if no other suggestions come up.)

**Update:** I also just tried re-navigating to new location; I turned screen off in the middle of the, "okay navigation all set" message. Then, the "you're on the fastest route" message played while screen off, but then all the directions no longer play, so issue still happening.

**Update 2:** I disabled bluetooth and restarted the phone, and the problem still exists. The voice directions also do not play when I have a different app in focus.  I'll try a fresh install of Google Maps at some point soon.

Comment: Is your device hooked up to any sort of Bluetooth in the car?

Comment: @tubedogg -- I disabled bluetooth, and the issue continues, even after a phone restart.

Comment: Did you every find a solution? My iphone is having this EXACT problem. I've uninstalled/reinstalled google maps. I have tried "reset all settings." I have done a wipe and restore on my phone. I have even tried restoring my backup to a completely different physical iphone and it STILL has the problem!! So it's clearly a software issue, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @John -- unfortunately no. It's my wife's phone, and she's just accepted this behavior. I meant to try debugging further (i.e. all the stuff you tried), but didn't get around to it. Not sure what else we can try :(

Comment: I'm also having this issue. There's definitely Bluetooth issues too, where it keeps trying to connect via Bluetooth. But even once I disable it, the turn-by-turn directions are announced just fine. Until I hit the lock button to turn the screen off and then everything goes silent.

Comment: Just wondering if anyone has found a solution for this. I’m using an iPhone SE and have had the same issue. I often use Waze with the screen off as my fallback, but would like to use Google Maps like this.

Comment: Enable "Play as bluetooth call" (Settings > Navigation) fix the same issue for me (No sound when the screen is off. Bluetooth is enabled, no BT device are connected).
See [Best 10 Fixes for Google Maps Voice Navigation Not Working on Android and iPhone - "4. Enable Play Voice Over Bluetooth"](https://www.guidingtech.com/fix-google-maps-voice-navigation-not-working-android-iphone/)

Answer (score -1):

There is a setting in it somewhere to allows notifications when in standby.

Comment: This answer isn't really useful unless you provide more detailed steps to enable this setting.